# Accessing Global Vars with Window

Tags: javascript, eval, jsfiddle

Why doesn't `window.x` print out `10`?

```
eval("var x = 10;");
console.log(window.x); // undefined
console.log(x); // 10
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kzd4z/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have selected `onLoad` in the side panel, which wraps everything in an anonymous function.  If you pick "No wrap" it works.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kzd4z/2/

You can see this by viewing source:

```
//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
eval("var x = 10;");
console.log(window.x); // undefined
console.log(x); // 10
}//]]>
```

Comment: Based on the source you provided, it's not obvious to me what the problem is. [I understand your explanation that it's wrapped in an anonymous function. As a result, the `this` context is not `window`(global) when defining `x`.]

Comment: `this` doesn't come in to play when defining `x` - `var` just means that the variable is local to the function, therefore it doesn't get attached to `window`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on **[@Dennis'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850833/dennis)** answer, because using "No Wrap" wraps your entire function within an anonymous function, x is now part of the local scope of that anonymous function. Like any function in javascript, using the keyword `var` creates this local variable... You can remove the "No Wrap" option on jsfiddle, or just drop the var keyword (creating a variable in the global scope).

```
eval("x = 10;");
console.log(window.x); // 10
console.log(x); // 10
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kzd4z/3/)**

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this looks like what is happening to me...